# Dynamic Data Web Application not paging past page 2

Tags: dynamic-data

I have created a Dynamic Data Web Application and when I have more then one page I am able to navigate to the second page and the last page however I am unable to navigate to any of the pages in between two and the last page....any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, and in my case, it was caused by broken filters.

I created a Textbox filter, and during development, I unwittingly added `OnFilterChanged();` in the FilterControl's `Page_Load` event for the sake of simplicity. Later, it was rendered obsolete as I copied it into the `TextChanged` event, as the former method has glitches.

Unfortunately, in List.aspx.cs, there lies the following code:

```
protected void DynamicFilter_FilterChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = 0;
}
```

As a result, at every page load, the PageIndex of GridView is reset. And since `Page_Load` is called before `DynamicFilter_FilterChanged` before the next page button's event handler, the result will be:

On any list page with more than one page:

- Clicking next whatever the current `PageIndex` navigates to page 2
- Clicking previous whatever the current `PageIndex` navigates to page 1
- Other navigation controls work as intended, including entering the page number.

To solve the problem, I just removed `OnFilterChanged();` from `Page_Load` in the filter.

You may need to check every third-party filter. Or, you may comment out the `DynamicFilter_FilterChanged` event to see if filters are to blame.